# About springdata mongodb aggregation

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

At present, I have a problem. I can use aggregate function in mongodb to query the corresponding data, but after using springdatamongodb, I find that lookup cannot use variables to convert string to objectid, so how should I write this aggregate function

**How can I write it as mongodb expression in spring data mogodb**

```
  db.getCollection('course').aggregate([{
            $unwind: '$studentIds',
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'student',
              let: { stuId: { $toObjectId: '$studentIds' } },
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    $expr: { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$stuId' ] },
                  },
                },
                {
                  $project: {
                    isSendTemplate: 1,
                    openId: 1,
                    stu_name: '$name',
                    stu_id: '$_id',
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: 'student',
            },
          }])
```

Comment: it would be easier to answer your question if you provide some sample records of your collection.

Answer (score 0):

For the complex and custom aggregation query, you can create a custom  [AggregationOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOperation.html) and then passed the aggregation json from Mongo shell, or what you have as it is. e.g:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationContext;

public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

  private String jsonOperation;

  public CustomAggregationOperation(String jsonOperation) {
    this.jsonOperation = jsonOperation;
  }

  @Override
  public org.bson.Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
    return aggregationOperationContext.getMappedObject(org.bson.Document.parse(jsonOperation));
  }
}
```

Now pass the `$lookup` query as it is in the above class from the the Aggregation query class as below:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypedAggregation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import sample.data.mongo.models.Course;

@Service
public class LookupAggregation {

  @Autowired
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public void LookupAggregationExample() {

    AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("studentIds");

    String query1 = "{$lookup: {from: 'student', let: { stuId: { $toObjectId: '$studentIds' } },"
        + "pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$stuId' ] },},}, "
        + "{$project: {isSendTemplate: 1,openId: 1,stu_name: '$name',stu_id: '$_id',},},], "
        + "as: 'student',}, }";

    TypedAggregation<Course> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Course.class,
        unwind,
        new CustomAggregationOperation(query1)
    );

    AggregationResults<Course> results =
        mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Course.class);
    System.out.println(results.getMappedResults());
  }
}
```

For more details, you can check my Github repo at : https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/blob/master/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb/src/main/java/sample/data/mongo/services/LookupAggregation.java